# Flutter image container, images next to each other

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, containers

I'm trying to make a home page and create this image container, of three images next to each other.
I tried doing it like this:

```dart
Container(
     height: 100.0,
     width: 150.0,
     child: Row(
         children:[
             Image(image: AssetImage('')),
         Column(
         children:[
             Image(image: AssetImage('')), 
             Image(image: AssetImage('')), 
             ],
            ),
          ],
        ), 
      ),
```

**what I get looks like this**

[image: what i get looks like this]

**while what I want is this**

[image: while what i want is this]

Although the results are nothing like this. Any ideas on how to recreate my figma image?

Comment: Please don't share your code as an image. If you would like the community's help, edit your question with the a snippet of code that illustrates what you are trying to do, what you see happening now and what you would like to happen.

Comment: im sorry, first time asking a question here that requests a code and i have no idea how to add it in a code form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `Image` widget,  provide `height` and `weight` and also use   `fit: BoxFit.cover,` for better view, then it will be good to go.

Your fine Container will be

```dart
 Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 150.0 + 4, //for padding
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    // for rounded border
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      child: const Image(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/p7_image_asset.jpeg'),
                        width: 150 / 2,
                        height: 100.0,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        // space between items
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, bottom: 2),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          child: Image(
                            image:
                                AssetImage('assets/images/p8_image_asset.jpeg'),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            height: 100 / 2 - 2, //-2 for padding
                            width: 150 / 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, top: 2),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          child: Image(
                            image:
                                AssetImage('assets/images/p9_image_asset.jpeg'),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            height: 100 / 2 - 2, //-2 for padding
                            width: 150 / 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

I will encourage to go [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/) and learn about these widgets. If you are wanting GridView check[flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

Comment: thank you, that works. and also flutter_staggered_grid_view works pretty well too.

Comment: yes use that only if you needed for GridView. also for inner text check `stack` widget